# Designated Survivor Vice President

Tags: plot-explanation, designated-survivor

Did I miss anything? Did President Kirkman ever nominate a new Vice President to replace Peter MacLeish? I don't recall anything being said about that.

Answer (score 3):

Update in regards to season 2 (I'm avoiding spoilers as best as I can).

Functionally speaking, between MacLeish and the new VP, Secretary Moss acted as Kirkman's mentor/confidant and is often shown to support Kirkman the way a VP would. This meant that for Kirkman, nominating a new VP was a less pressing issue than it otherwise would have been.

Kirkman ends up nominating a new VP in S02E14 "In the dark". When announcing the nomination, he addresses the fact that he did not immediately nominate a new VP after MacLeish, because he took his time finding the right VP.

In the beginning of the episode, Kirkman mentions that it's not *necessary* to nominate a VP ([link](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=designated-survivor-2016&episode=s02e14))

> You're both focused on the politics here. I think you're missing the point. The point is **we don't need to have a Vice President right now**. The line of succession of the presidency's already in place: Speaker of the House, President of the Senate, both of whom have been elected to their positions.
>   Both have earned the right to serve, unlike anyone I could simply appoint.
>
> Tyler, Fillmore, Johnson (Andrew, not Lyndon) and Arthur all succeeded Presidents who died who while they were in office. Not a single one of them appointed a Vice President.

Kirkman then continues that since there is no requirement for it, it's better to wait until the right VP is found.

> The first man that I appointed Vice President was involved in a massive conspiracy that almost brought our country down and cost me my life. We're gonna get this right. **We're gonna wait until we find the perfect candidate.**

Later in the episode, he does decide to nominate a VP. The relevant part of his address to the nation ([link](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=designated-survivor-2016&episode=s02e14)):

> We are all too well aware of the tragic and treasonous circumstances that surrounded Vice President Peter MacLeish.
>   Those **circumstances left me uncertain about how to fill that role**.
>   I wanted someone with clarity of thought, someone who had a sense of purpose, someone who would speak their mind and challenge me to become a better leader, someone who understood that there is a time when principled opposition needs to give way for the greater good.
>
> And to be honest, I did not think that I would find that candidate. But I was wrong.
>   So it is with great pleasure and pride that I introduce to you my nominee for Vice President of the United States of America, [spoiler redacted].

Answer (score 2):

## NO.

Not that I can find. That post is currently vacant* which would put the Speaker of the House as next in line (IIRC).

<sup>*I confess this does seem like something they should be addressing</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** The role went to his original chief of staff (towards season 3) Aaron Shore.

However, for a long time the role was vacant following the scandal of MacLeish

Comment: The role was only temporarily vacant. There was a Veep appointed by Kirkman before Aaron Shore. Also, review the answer from @Flater.